# How to create a CSV with a list inside a list?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a CSV file, but don't understand how I can break down the records.

In my code I have these 2 classes

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleShop
{
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public List<Car> CarsForSale { get; set; }
}
```

I generate cars with shops:

```
Car Ford = new Car()
{
    Brand = "Ford",
    Color = "Black",
    FuelType = "Petrol"
};
Car BMW = new Car()
{
    Brand = "BMW",
    Color = "Yellow",
    FuelType = "Petrol"
};
Car Nissan = new Car()
{
    Brand = "Nissan",
    Color = "Red",
    FuelType = "Diesel"
};

VehicleShop Shop1 = new VehicleShop()
{
    ShopName = "Shop 1"
};
Shop1.CarsForSale.Add(Ford);
Shop1.CarsForSale.Add(BMW);

VehicleShop Shop2 = new VehicleShop()
{
    ShopName = "Shop 1"
};
Shop2.CarsForSale.Add(Ford);
Shop2.CarsForSale.Add(BMW);
Shop2.CarsForSale.Add(Nissan);
```

I want to put all this data into a CSV to look like this

```
ShopName,Brand,Color,FuelType
Shop 1,Ford,Black,Petrol
Shop 1,BMW,Yellow,Petrol
Shop 2,Ford,Black,Petrol
Shop 2,BMW,Yellow,Petrol
Shop 2,Nissan,Red,Diesel
```

I just don't know where to begin accessing elements inside a list like that.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want/need to use CSV? That format isn't really meant for child collections.

Comment: The fundamental approach here will involve using `GroupBy()` on the raw CSV data, where you group by the `ShopName` value. Each group will form the list you want. See duplicate for example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ah yes, thanks mate